# Code to accept resume and cover letter over FTP using C#

Tags: c#, ftp

Having completed an independent coding task, I then asked a few professional developers for their feedback as to what they think of the project I presented. Given that I am not an expert c# programmer I made quite a few mistakes. How can I improve the following block of code?

```
public class application ()
{

    private void UploadApplicationFiles(Application application)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(application.resume) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(application.cover_letter) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(application.app_pdf))
        {
            var applicantKey = GetAttachedRecordKey(applicant);

            var resume = GetResumes(application);
            var coverLetter = GetCoverLetter(application);
            var pdfapplication = GetApplication(application);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resume))
            {
                var upload = UploadAttachment(resume, application.resume, applicantKey);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(coverLetter))
            {
                var upload = UploadAttachment(coverLetter, application.cover_letter, applicantKey);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pdfapplication))
            {
                var upload = UploadAttachment(pdfapplication, application.app_pdf, applicantKey);
            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetResumes(applications_v2 application)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(application.resume))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        application.resume = GetFileName(application.resume);
        var ftpfullpath = $"{ResumeSource}/{application.id}/{application.resume}";
        var file = $"{application.first_name}{application.last_name}_{MakeValidFileName(application.resume)}";
        var fileName = Path.Combine(ResumeShare, file);

        try
        {
            using (var requestcClient = new WebClient())
            {
                requestcClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUsr, FtpPwd);
                requestcClient.Proxy = null;
                requestcClient.DownloadFile(ftpfullpath, fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            fileName = string.Empty;
            Console.WriteLine($"error downloading resume {fileName}, {exception}");
        }

        return fileName;
    }

    private static string GetCoverLetter(applications_v2 application)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(application.cover_letter))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        application.cover_letter = GetFileName(application.cover_letter);
        var ftpfullpath = $"{ResumeSource}/{application.id}/{application.cover_letter}";
        var file = $"{application.first_name}{application.last_name}_{MakeValidFileName(application.cover_letter)}";

        var fileName = Path.Combine(ResumeShare, file);

        try
        {
            using (var requestcClient = new WebClient())
            {
                requestcClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUsr, FtpPwd);
                requestcClient.Proxy = null;
                requestcClient.DownloadFile(ftpfullpath, fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            fileName = string.Empty;
            Console.WriteLine($"error downloading resume {fileName}, {exception}");
        }

        return fileName;
    }

    private static string GetApplication(applications_v2 application)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(application.app_pdf))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        application.app_pdf = GetFileName(application.app_pdf);
        var ftpfullpath = $"{ResumeSource}/{application.id}/{application.app_pdf}";
        var file = $"{application.first_name}{application.last_name}_{MakeValidFileName(application.app_pdf)}";
        var fileName = Path.Combine(ResumeShare, file);

        try
        {
            using (var requestcClient = new WebClient())
            {
                requestcClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUsr, FtpPwd);
                requestcClient.Proxy = null;
                requestcClient.DownloadFile(ftpfullpath, fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            fileName = string.Empty;
            Console.WriteLine($"error downloading resume {fileName}, {exception}");
        }

        return fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a job-interview-question?

Comment: No this is a personal project for a portfolio

Comment: I think you can put `var resume = GetResumes(application)` etc in their respective `if` blocks, then get rid of the outer `if`. Also, you might want to consider creating a single generic GetDocument function, and passing a parameter that tells it what document to get, rather than having a separate function for each document type.

Comment: you never do anything with the `var upload` variable in `UploadApplicationFiles`

Comment: @Acccumulation Do not answer in comments. Please write an answer, even if it is short.

Comment: Where is `applicant`in the call of  `GetAttachedRecordKey(applicant)` coming from ? Incomplete code is bordering off-topicness.

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things, not at all complete:

- First things first: Your code is incomplete, which makes it very hard to give any meaningful critique. Consider posting at least complete classes next time. There might very well be some things that are fine in wider context of the whole class (though I think the points below will stand anyway).
- C# naming conventions state that classes (and methods and properties, ...) should be named using PascalCase.
- You're not doing anything with `upload` after the calls to `UploadAttachment`.
- You're violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) with your class. It (at least going by its name) represents an application, but is also in charge of uploading files to a remote server. It would be nicer if you'd separate those concerns into different classes.
- This is linked to the point above: Why does your `application` class need to know about credentials? That should really be somewhere else.
- You are repeating yourself quite a bit in your `GetXXX` methods. Just a quick mock up of how you could condense those:

  ```
  // call this with application.Coverletter, application.AppPdf, ...
  // I renamed 'applications_v2' to 'Application' to match C# conventions
  private static string DownloadFile(string file, Application application)
  {
      if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file))
      {
          return string.Empty;
      }
      var fileName = GetFileName(file);
      var remotePath = $"{ResumeSource}/{application.Id}/{fileName}";
      var localName = $"{Application.FirstName}{Application.LastName}_{MakeValidFileName(fileName)}";
      localName = Path.Combine(ResumeShare, remoteName);

      try
      {
          using(var client = new WebClient())
          {
              client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUsr, FtpPwd);
              client.DownloadFile(remotePath, localName);
          }
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          localName = string.Empty;
          // logging...
      } 

      return localName;
  }
  ```
- You are mutating your `application` instance in the `GetXXX` methods. That's surprising as you are already returning the result of the method. I would either mutate the `application` and return `void` or return `string` and not mutate the `application`.